# c# UWP Getting access to path denied when writing bytes to a new file after array created by DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, file-permissions

I set file permission of directory Everyone full control, but still get error.

THE ERROR
[image]

THE CODE

```
        /// Handles a frame arrived event and renders the frame to the screen.
    /// </summary>
    private void FrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TryAcquireLatestFrame will return the latest frame that has not yet been acquired.
        // This can return null if there is no such frame, or if the reader is not in the
        // "Started" state. The latter can occur if a FrameArrived event was in flight
        // when the reader was stopped.

        // Get frame image from camera:
        using (MediaFrameReference  frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())   //  ==>  MediaFrameReference 
        {
            // Got image?
            if (frame != null)
            {
                                    // DIAG: Save image data to file for analysis:
                                        // Get image byte data: 
                                            DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer( frame.BufferMediaFrame.Buffer );
                                            byte[] camera_image_bytes = new byte[ frame.BufferMediaFrame.Buffer.Length];
                                            dataReader.ReadBytes( camera_image_bytes );

                                        // Save to file :
                                            var len =  camera_image_bytes.Length;
                                            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes( "C:\\PRIMARY\\WORK\\CAMERA READER\\camera_image_bytes.bin", camera_image_bytes );  <<<<<<<<<<<   E R R O R   H E R E
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to save there at all, since the point of UWP applications is to run across a range of devices, some of them might not have a concept of the "C:\" drive. You'll have to write to an application local folder.

Comment: What "local folder" can I use that I can get to on my C driver?  (not running this on other devices yet -- just doing diagnostics)

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct: your app doesn't have access to C:\PRIMARY\WORK\CAMERA READER\ . UWP apps run with a subset of the user's permissions and by default can directly write only to their application data folders. See the UWP [File Access Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) documentation for more details.

Your user can grant the app brokered access to other areas via several means, most likely being the [FileSavePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker) (to let the user pick where to save) or declared [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) such as picturesLibrary or broadFileSystemAccess. See [Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) These methods will allow the app to access the folder via the file broker and the [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) and StorageFolder objects.

From what you present here that should be sufficient. [Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync) is very similar to your System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes call. If you need to use System.IO instead of Windows.Storage you can get a brokered HANDLE via [IStorageItemHandleAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/windowsstoragecom/nn-windowsstoragecom-istorageitemhandleaccess) and then use that to initialize System.IO.FileStreams and such.

Comment: Where on my C: drive will I find my  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder files, when I run my app on my Windows 10 computer?

Comment: It depends on the system. You can get the path from the LocalFolder's StorageFolder.Path variable. If this is intended to be user data rather than app data (i.e that it's available to users from outside of the app) then you should but it somewhere users are likely to look, such as a user-chosen location or the pictures library (assuming it's a picture). If the data is intended to be used only through the app then LocalFolder is the right location.